# Meteorjs Javascript Files Not Executing (Requires Refresh)

Tags: javascript, meteor, refresh

Not sure how to word the question which is probably why I haven't found a solution when looking through stackoveflow for a solution.  But...

When I try to implement code like the sample found here that attaches an active class to the nav links (https://coderwall.com/p/ahlrua) I sometimes have to hit refresh after navigating to a new page to see that link actually goes active.  My guess is that since the js file has already been loaded to the client-side there is no subsequent call to the file when I navigate to new pages? If this is the case, even if not, how the heck do I fix this?

This behavior as I mentioned happens in other places for me when I use Meteorjs, ie my breadcrumbs always need refreshing after going to a new page.  I'm fairly new to this framework so forgive my ignorance.

Here's my staging site that I'm working on that has this/these issues: http://jdd.meteor.com/

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to refresh browser to see active link because code responsible for activating link is not reactive :

```
// Get the current path for URL
curPath = function() {
  var c = window.location.pathname;
  var b = c.slice(0, -1);
  var a = c.slice(-1);
  if(b === "") {
    return "/";
  } else {
    if(a === "/") {
      return b;
    } else {
      return c;
    }
  }
};
```

It only checks the url when template is being rendered not when `window.location.pathname` is changed.

One of possible solutions is to use [IronRouter](http://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) together with package [IronRouterActive](https://github.com/XpressiveCode/iron-router-active/).

Usage is very simple:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="{{ isActiveRoute 'dashboard' }}">...</li>
        <li class="{{ isActiveRoute 'dashboard|root' }}">...</li>
        <li class="{{ isActiveRoute 'users' 'on' }}">...</li>
        <li class="{{ isActivePath 'products' }}">...</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Example source](https://github.com/XpressiveCode/iron-router-active/)

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go.  However, this problem pervades other aspects of my site (ie breadcrumbs).  Perhaps when I look into this though it will also remedy that situation.  Will try this later today.  Thanks again.